# tabs at the bottom of TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I get the Tab Control to place the tabs at the bottom of the control and not at the top

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open the properties window go to property **Alignment** and set it to **Bottom**

Answer (score 6):

6 years later, it is now

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom"/>
```

Comment: The question is about a WinForms Tab Control, this answer is for a WPF Tab Control.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set the tab alignment programatically, take a look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.alignment(VS.80).aspx)

```
    // Positions tabs on the bottom of tabControl1
    this.tabControl1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.TabAlignment.Bottom;
```